# Internationalize Forum Posts Without Translating Them

Tags: permalinks, localization, plugin-polylang

I would like to internationalize my forum.
I would like for users to be able to display the forum in 2 languages.

The language will be determined by the url.

I downloaded a plugin called [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) to help me with this.

This works well until it comes to displaying posts (ie: questions).
I'm interested in displaying the posts in their original language regardless of the user's current locale (ie: page elements such as header and footer will reflect the user's locale while the post will be in its original language).

I would like a given post to have urls like:
www.example.com/blog/fr/some-post
www.example.com/blog/ru/some-post

Is this possible? The only possibility to do this with Polylang would be to enter the exact same post for each language. But it seems inefficient and incorrect to do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin WPGlobus allowed me to achieve what I stated in the question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/116603)

Comment: There is no link. I'm referencing the question above.

Comment: The answer have only a plugin name, no content in this context. Answers should also help other readers, also solid without external content, solutions.